# Pull non-minimized values out of function being minimized with SciPy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, function, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am having trouble pulling out values out of a function that I am trying to optimize. The code looks similar to what follows. I want to minimize c by changing x through scipy.optimize.minimize, but am also trying to pull a and b out of the function as well. What is the best way to do this?

```
def function(x, inputs)

a = math
b = math
c = math

return(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just compute `a` and `b` outside of the function. It doesn't need to be part of the `function` if the result is not optimized. Just use `x`, `inputs`, and `c` to compute `a` and `b` outside of the function.